# windows server: convert xls file format to csv or xlsx without office installed using vba or powershell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, export-to-csv

Does anyone know how to convert existing XLS files to either CSV or XLSX format using VBA or Powershell on a Windows Server that does not have Office installed on it?

Links and code examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Any kind of script, either VBA or Powershell, will eventually need the Excel component to make the conversion. I found a gist that uses Powershell , but that will call upon Excel objects too... Maybe if you install a trial or something would be enough, since your not actually using the software. https://gist.github.com/gabceb/954418

Comment: @stevenvanc Installing a trial for this would almost certainly be a violation of the license (and it would expire anyway). Even if you aren't using it interactively, you're still "using" it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I see the value in converting XLS to XLSX as both are usable by the same applications.

To convert XLS to CSV without a dependency upon Excel, check out the [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel) module.

`Import-Excel -path PATH_TO_EXCELFILE | export-csv -notypeinfo -path PATH_TO_CSVFILE` may be all you need. I'm away from a Windows machine at the moment so I can't test that but it'll get you started.

Comment: The reason converting to XLSX is an option is because it is accessible as an XML doc and thus easier to convert to CSV without Office.

Comment: looking into this further, the ImportExcel module uses EPPlus.dll for it's conversion, and EPPLus cannot read old XLS formats, only XLSX.  Hence, I would still need to either do the conversion, or find something that reads XLS.